# Murray 15AMP tripping at 4.3AMP

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I bought my house 3 years ago and it was completely remodeled before I bought it. It has new Murray MP-AT2 15AMP breakers. Recently two of the breakers keep tripping off at very low amperage. I just tested one and it tripped at 4.3 AMPS. Any reason why it would do this? Should I just buy new breakers and hope it fixes the issue?

Comment: Really tripping overcurrent? Or AFCI?

Comment: Yes -- are these overcurrent, arc fault, or arc-to-ground trips?

Comment: All google searches for MP-AT2 seem to suggest this is a breaker that includes both **overcurrent** and **AFCI** protection.  Do you know what that second one is?  Does the offending appliance do this on every such breaker?

Comment: what do the LED indicators say? Arc-faults are very hard to track down.